# How do I test for Truthy and Falsy in this generalized ruby method for reduce?

Tags: ruby, reduce

This is for a ruby course.  We're being asked to write a generalized
method for reduce.

```rb
def my_own_reduce(array, starting_point = 0)
   final_total =  array.reduce(starting_point) { |sum, num| sum + num}
end
```

Here are the error messages I'm getting:

```
 # my own reduce returns a running total when given a starting point
 # my own reduce returns true when all values are truthy
# my own reduce returns false when any value is false
 # my own reduce returns true when a truthy value is present
 # my own reduce returns false when no truthy value is present
```

Comment: First of all, if you hardcode `+`, it's not "generalized". Secondly, I doubt that the task "write a generalized method for reduce" will judge well a solution that merely wraps the native Ruby `reduce`. Thirdly, if you are giving out errors, it would be nice to know what inputs cause them (for example, I have no idea why "my own reduce returns a running total when given a starting point" is an error, I'd guess that's the desired behaviour).

Comment: I believe you are begin asked to create an instance method `Enumerable#my_own_reduce` that behaves the same as `Enumerable#reduce`. Since `reduce` optionally takes an argument it must look like `module Enumerable; def my_own_reduce(obj = nil); <your code, which involves yielding to a block>; end`. This is a non-trivial task for a newbie.

Comment: Presumably your method is being tested against unseen expressions. The second, "return `true` when all values are truthy", might be, for example, `[1,2,nil,'cat'].my_own_reduce(true) { |t_or_f,e| t_or_f & e  }` with the required return value of `false`. See [TrueClass#&](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/TrueClass.html#method-i-26) and [FalseClass#&](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.4/FalseClass.html#method-i-26)...

Comment: ... The fourth test might be: `[nil,'cat',false].my_own_reduce(false) { |t_or_f,e| t_or_f | e  }` with the required return value of `true`. See [TrueClass#|](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/TrueClass.html#method-i-7C) and [FalseClass#|](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.4/FalseClass.html#method-i-7C).

Answer (score 1):

All values in Ruby are truthy except for `nil` and `false`.

If you want to convert a non-boolean object into a boolean, based on its truthiness, you can use a 'double bang' operator, as in the following example:

```
some_value = 42
some_other_value = 0
yet_another_value = nil

puts !!some_value # => true
puts !!some_other_value # => true
puts !!yet_another_value # => false
```

To use the truthiness of an object in conditions you can simply use them as you would booleans. Like so:

```
def my_method(my_argument)
  if my_argument
    'Received a truthy argument'
  else
    'Received a falsy argument'
  end
end

puts my_method(0) # => 'Received a truthy argument'
puts my_method(nil) # => 'Received a falsy argument'
puts my_method(false) # => 'Received a falsy argument'
```

I hope this helps, but without a little more information about the context of your question I'm not sure I can tell you much more. The error messages you posted are more than a little unclear and even contradictory.

Does the condition "when given a starting point" mean a starting point other than the default value of 0?

The conditions "any value is false" and "a truthy value is present" could easily both be met, the given array could quite simply contain one of each. In this case, which condition should take precedence?